Is it grammatically correctly to say "hamper me from something"?
Is it grammatically correctly to say "hamper me from something"?
E.g.: "The lack of vocabulary doesn't hamper me from trying to speak".
It seems to me that "hamper me" sounds unnatural but I can't explain why so I'm not sure.
Is my understanding correct that you could say "The lack of vocabulary doesn't hamper my progress" or "For me, the lack of vocabulary doesn't hamper (from) speaking" but not "hamper me"?
P.S. I understand that it's possible to say "My lack of vocabulary doesn't stop me from trying to speak" or "The lack of vocabulary doesn't prevent me from trying to speak" but I'm interested here exactly in usage of "hamper".

Hamper is best used with a complement that is an activity, rather than an agent. Thus, The lack of vocabulary doesn’t hamper my attempts at speaking. What is or isn’t hampered is not you, but your attempts.
Note, by the way, that it would be more idiomatic to say, “my lack” than “the lack.”
Note too that you might actually want the verb hinder instead of hamper. It would be used in the same way (hinder your attempts, not you).
